# Cloudflare for saas, how to enable for agency saas in the middle

Tags: cloudflare

we can white label nice saas domain nicely under which we can install custom hostname and other things nicely.. The problem is, we need to allow agencies to make their own white label saas under their own domain name. We are stuck for this setup.. Anyone can help?